# Why is the script not running , but only code is showing on webpage

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following input field and I want to show a text on the webpage with some jQuery code if the input field is selected.

```
<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="radio" <?php if($no_of_payments_per_year == "1"){ echo 'checked="checked"'; echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#numberSelected").text("half yearly");</script>'; } ?> name="no_of_payments_per_year" />
```

How can I get the jQuery to run? I am sure there is some syntax that I am missing here. Below is the output on the webpage, so just showing the code!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just took the script out of the input field and defined a variable instead and ran a function with the script. That solved the issue. I was trying to do too many things in just one line and it got too complicated.

```
$selected = 0;
<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="radio" <?php if($no_of_payments_per_year == "1"){ echo 'checked="checked"'; $selected = 1;} ?> >

            <script>
            
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                paymentsSelected(<?=$selected?>);
            
            });
            
            
            
            function paymentsSelected($var){
                // alert($var);
                if($var == '1'){
                    $('#numberSelected').text('yearly');
                }
                if($var == '2'){
                    $('#numberSelected').text('half yearly');
                }
                if($var == '4'){
                    $('#numberSelected').text('quarterly');
                }
                if($var == '12'){
                    $('#numberSelected').text('monthly');
                }
                
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're PHP is broken. [It's outputting this](https://3v4l.org/sldgv):

```
<input style="margin-left: 15px;" type="radio" checked="checked" <script type="text/javascript">$("#numberSelected").text("half yearly");</script> name="no_of_payments_per_year" />
```

The initial `<input>` tag was never closed - it's missing a `>` before the script. This causes the browser to fail to parse the opening `<script>` tag and therefore fail to parse your JavaScript as JavaScript.

You can debug these issues yourself by viewing the page source.

Comment: _"The initial <input> tag was never closed"_ - it kinda was, but _after_ the script element. I am guessing OP wasn't aware that they can not just insert a script element arbitrarily _within_ other tags.

Comment: I deleted the "/" in "/>" at the end and now the code is not showing any more in the browser, but the code is still not executing